# How to Edit node label of treeview without raising events

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, treenode

Maybe the header doesn't make sense, but what I want to do is in `OnBeforeLabelEdit` remove the suffix from the node.

There is a problem however, because when I write `node.Label.Text = "Some text without suffix"`, the node probably cancels the edit after the suffix is removed.

Can someone help me how to edit the node label text in this event of `OnBeforeLabelEdit` without cancelling the user's editing?

Comment: _There is a problem however, because when I write node.Label.Text = "Some text without suffix", the node probably cancels the edit_ Um, do not thrwo a probably at us and don't post code that doesn't even compile!

Comment: [This](http://www.cyotek.com/blog/specifying-custom-text-when-using-the-labeledit-functionality-of-a-treeview) looks promising. Unfortunately during the regular BeforeLabelEdit the EditControl is not created yet..